# "champions of..." vs "champions in..."

Tags: meaning, word-usage, prepositions

Someone asked me what the difference is between "We are the champions OF the world" and "We are the champions IN the world". 
I couldn't really explain other than saying "of" is more commonly used and sounds more final/definitive.
How would you describe the difference in meaning/nuance between these two sentences?

Comment: Of course *the champions of the world* is far more common. Like what you feel, I think the sentence with **of** sounds more definitive. I'm not sure, but maybe because **of** implies the possessiveness, while **in** implies a part of the whole!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me,

> "We are the champions in the world"

has no meaning.

Yes, the world is the *only* place where you can be the champion, so no need to say it unnecessarily.

> We are the champions OF the world.

Says: "You are the best, better than everyone in the world."